# Sequelize cannot include with count attribute

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

guys. I have the following problem. I've got two entities, where one event can have many participants like the following:

```
class Event {
    name: string;
    participants: Participant[];
}

class Participant {
    eventId: string;
    event: Event;
    fullName: string;
}
```

I would like to create a query, which will count for me numbers of participants. So I created a query like this:

```
await Event.findAll({
      attributes: [
        "Event.id",
        "participants.id",
        [Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("participants.id")), "participantCount"],
      ],
      include: [
        {
          model: Participant,
          as: "participants",
          required: false,
          attributes: ["id"],
        },
      ],
      raw: true,
      group: ["Event.id", "participants.id"],
    });
```

But the problem is with an error during exacution as follow:

```
"message": "attr[0].indexOf is not a function",
"stack": "TypeError: attr[0].indexOf is not a function\n    at attributes.map.attr
```

My version of sequelize is 4.41.1. Have you got this kind of error? If yes, I will be very grateful for the help.

Comment: Have you tried removing the Sequelize.fn and then running to see if that is the line of error ..?

Comment: Not sure if this will help... but if you want total counts per event, then you need to get rid of all references to participants.id *except* for the COUNT function.  Remove from a) Event attributes. b) Participant attributes (should be`attributes: []` and c) group.

Comment: @shiva2492 without this line, everything works correctly.

Comment: @KenOn10 I tried it, and I've got the same error.

Comment: @AlojzyMucha your code looks OK - my working app has a lot of similar code.  1) does Sequelize log the SQL before the error occurs?  2) can you share your association code, probably `Event.hasMany(Participant)`?

Comment: @KenOn10 No, it doesn't log any SQL. I think that the problem is related to the Sequelize.fn clause. 
Event has decorator like here: ```@HasMany(() => Participant)
  public participants: Participant[];```
On Participant it looks like this: ```@AllowNull(false)
  @Column
  @ForeignKey(() => Event)
  public eventId: string;

  @BelongsTo(() => Event)
  public event: Event;```

Comment: @AlojzyMucha  to isolate the problem, try replacing the fn() with `[Sequelize.literal('COUNT(participants.id)'), 'participantCount']`?  Or `Sequelize.literal('COUNT(participants.id) as participantCount')`

Comment: @KenOn10
Still the same error. In your codebase which version of sequelize do you have? Maybe my version has an issue related to the library implementation?

Comment: @AlojzyMucha I just started using 4.44.3 a couple of days ago - couldn't hurt to update.

Comment: Do you need participants list or just the count of participants?

Comment: @RohitDalal only the count of participants.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need the count you can use two methods - **Sequelize Query** or **Raw Query**

**Sequelize Query**

```
    Event.findAll({
      attributes: [
       "id",
       [Sequelize.literal('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM participants P WHERE 
        P.eventId=events.id'), "participantCount"]
      ]
    });
```

**Raw Query**

```
    Db.sequelize.query(`
        SELECT E.id,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM participants P WHERE P.eventId=E.id) as participantCount
        FROM events E
    `, { 
         type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
    });
```

** Db here is the sequelize connection.